# Trying to share a folder from windows 7 to any device on network

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

Basically I want to share a folder from a windows 7 (Ultimate) PC to other windows/linux PCs running on the network.

**Server Settings:**
Trying to share folder D:\Media

R-Click -> Properties -> Sharing
Shared as path "\\JB-PC\Media"
Permissions - Everyone - Read/Write

R-Click -> Properties -> Security
Everyone - Full Control (not how I want it, but I'm trying everything)

ControlPanel -> Network and Sharing -> Advanced Sharing Settings
Network Discovery - ON
File and Printer Sharing - ON
Public Folder Sharing - ON
File Sharing Connections - Enable for 40-56 bit encryption
Password protected Sharing - OFF

**Client**
Testing with windows 7 home
I can see the PC on the network, but the only folder I can access is **Users**.
Browsing to \\JB-PC\Media says "Cannot access" - check name and etc.

Is there anything I'm missing? I'm trying to share it to a variety of devices, so I'm not interested in sharing to a homegroup or the like.
Just anyone connected to the network should be able to see it.

Comment: Have you tried to map the folder as a network drive? Does that work?

Comment: @jer no I get the same issue. "Windows cannot access \\jb-pc\media"

Comment: In computer management under shares does the folder show as shared? Have you tried turning off the firewall and seeing if it works?

Answer (score 0):

**Doh!**
It turns out I had 2 computers on the network with the same name.

Renamed one of the clients and it's working smoothly.